# Tensorflow Object Detection using Tensorflow Mobile

Tags: android, mobile, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to use a custom model in the [TF-Detect Android Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android).

model: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco

The model is trained on 8 classes. After exporting the model I've optimised it using [Tensorflow-Mobile](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/mobile_intro)

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
    --in_graph=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
    --out_graph=optimized_inf_graph.pb \
    --inputs='image_tensor' \
    --outputs='detection_boxes detection_scores detection_classes num_detections' \
    --transforms='fold_batch_norms  fold_old_batch_norms  quantize_weights'
```

The graph is giving proper output in my local system, but when it's integrated in the application there is no output shown in the screen. Also the detection is wrong.
But when I'm using the unoptimised graph (`frozen_inference_graph.pb`) in the application, it's working fine. I'm getting outputs.

What am I doing wring here?